# SPO | Check existing scope and permissions of SharePoint add-ins/Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, sharepoint-addin

In SPO, i have registered few add-ins/Apps that are visible in **/_layouts/appprincipals.aspx** page.

I have already updated the permissions and the scope for these add-ins/apps but I am not able to find the updated permissions and scope anywhere?

Where I can find the scope and permissions of the add-ins/apps which i have already trusted?

Please Note: These apps/add-ins are not displayed in Site contents page